# What is the side effect of GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

While using sv2pdf in a project, I faced a `Failed to parse source map` error. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599784/failed-to-parse-source-map) solution and now it's resolved. The solution was to just add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to the `.env` file.

However, I am not sure about the possible side effects of this solution. According to the official Create React App [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/), it is ignored while in `development` yet used in `production`. Am I risking something by using this?

Answer (score 5):

> A source map is a file that maps from the transformed source to the original source, enabling the browser to reconstruct the original source and present the reconstructed original in the debugger. [Mozilla](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/how_to/use_a_source_map/index.html)

When the `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP` is enabled a full copy of your app's source code is bundled alongside the "minified" / "transcompiled" version of JS files.

If you enable this (`GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true`), the original source files will be visible to your app's visitors using tools like browser "Dev Tools".

And if you turn it off (`GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`), it won't create the source map files when you `build` your project (source maps are generated by default in production mode in CRA).