# unable to print value of state. How is state getting updated?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write a code in which `state` is initially set to a `user` object. When value of `textbox` is changed then the `state` should be updated. The code runs with warning and errors. How do I get rid of them? I also have few questions on how the code works (`... state` update bit as I copied it from a tutorial.

`User` is defined as

```
export default class User {
        constructor(email = '', password = '') {
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
    
module.exports = User;
```

The `component` is (I confess, I don't really appreciate how the `...state` is being used below (took code from a tutorial). I think I know what is does in general but I understand how it works in the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Col, Row, Container, Card,Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import User from 'models/user.js'
import { model } from 'mongoose';

let Register = () => {

    let [state,setState] = useState({user: new User()}); //shall I do user: new User or just new User. What would be the difference?

    let updateInput = (e) =>{
        setState({
            user: {
                ...state, //do I need this?
                ...state.user, //does this expand to user.emailand user.password?
                [e.target.name] : e.target.value //I suppose the target names should match the names of User object
            }    
        })
    }

    let register = (e) =>{
        console.log(`registerclick`)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Container className='mt-3'>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={3}>
                        <Card className="shadow-lg">
                            <Card.Header className='p-3'>
                                 Register
                            </Card.Header>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Form>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                                        <Form.Control name="email" onChange={updateInput} type="text" placeholder="email"/>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">    
                                        <Form.Control name="password" onChange={updateInput} type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                                    </Form.Group>                                    
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">    
                                        <Button onClick={register} type="submit">Register</Button>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Register;
```

On running the code, I get warning and error (though the page shows)

```
REDMOND+manuchadha@DESKTOP-6LMELP9 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - Microsoft/Manu_Personal/leren/views/reactfrontend (main)
$
Compiled with warnings.

Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\views\reactfrontend\node_modules\react-bootstrap\dist\module.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\views\reactfrontend\node_modules\react-bootstrap\dist\module.js.map'

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\views\reactfrontend\node_modules\react-bootstrap\dist\module.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\views\reactfrontend\node_modules\react-bootstrap\dist\module.js.map'

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Failed to parse source map" warning is unrelated to your code snippet.

See here: [Failed to parse source map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599784/failed-to-parse-source-map)

As far as your state, you can simplify like so:

```
const [userState, setUserState] = useState<User>(new User());

const updateInput = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) =>{
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value; 

    setUserState((prevState) => {
        // ensure that "name" is a valid User property
        if (Object.keys(prevState).includes(name)) { 
            return {
                ...prevState,
                [name]: value, // if non-string property, you'd need to validate datatype
            };
        }
        // If the name doesn't match a valid property, return the previous state.
        return prevState;
    });
}
```